# Pack and unpack integers in bit mask

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I want to pack `lod` in 2 bits and `x,y,z` each in 10 bits (what makes 32bit in summ). So far I coded this https://jsfiddle.net/wgdphzL1/2/:

```
console.clear();

var mask = 0;
var lod = 3;
var x = 5;
var y = 8;
var z = 5;

mask|=(lod & 3);
mask|=(x & 1023) << 10;
mask|=(y & 1023) << 20;
mask|=(z & 1023) << 30;


var lodr = mask & 3;
var xr = (mask >> 10) & 1023;
var yr = (mask >> 20) & 1023;
var zr = (mask >> 30) & 1023;

console.log(lodr, xr, yr, zr); // 3 5 8 1
```

And it works except the last `zr` in incorrect. And that's my problem. Feels like i'm going over 32bit limit, but theoretically should not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out I was wasting some bits at the beginning. Solution is:

```
console.clear();

var mask = 0;

var lod = 3;
var x = 5;
var y = 8;
var z = 12;

mask|=(lod & 3); 
mask|=(x & 1023) << 2; 
mask|=(y & 1023) << 12; 
mask|=(z & 1023) << 22; 


var lodr = mask & 3;
var xr = (mask >> 2) & 1023;
var yr = (mask >> 12) & 1023;
var zr = (mask >>> 22);

console.log(lodr, xr, yr, zr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is probably, that the mask is too big, so you are pushing it over the limit. Run this code toe see:

`(1<<30).toString(2)` it the max.

```js
console.info((1<<30).toString(2))
```

Comment: Any ideas for an solution?